# Can't apply bootstrap class table into a rails view

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't apply properly the table class of bootstrap in a rails view. Bootstrap's lib are correctly included because I can apply the rounded corner to an existing image. Any idea?

```js
<table class="table table-hover">
<% @city.fields.each do |field| %>
    <tr>
      <td>
          <% case field.kind %>
            <% when 'futbol'%>
              <%= link_to image_tag("futbol.jpg", class:"img-rounded", alt: "Futbol"),'http://rubyonrails.org/' %>
            <% when 'futsal'%>
              <%= link_to image_tag("polillerena.jpg", class:"img-rounded", alt: "Futbol sala"),'http://rubyonrails.org/' %>
            <% when 'padel'%>
              <%= link_to image_tag("raqueta_padel.jpg", class:"img-rounded", alt: "Padel"),'http://rubyonrails.org/' %>
            <% when 'pingpong'%>
              <%= link_to image_tag("pingpong.jpg", class:"img-rounded", alt: "Ping Pong"),'http://rubyonrails.org/' %>
            <% when 'tenis'%>
              <%= link_to image_tag("raqueta_tenis.jpg", class:"img-rounded", class:"img-rounded", alt: "Tenis"),'http://rubyonrails.org/' %>
          <% end %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p><h2><%= field.name %></h2></p>
        <p><%= field.other %></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: table class will get applied only to table structure not the div structure.. Your structure is totally wrong !! You cannot include div's like this in a table. Use td tr th inside a table then you can use div insisde thode tr/td..

Comment: You're right. I had it wrong. It's my first app. Thank you very much :)

Comment: No problem. If you need any help just post :)

Comment: How can I set the width equivalent to col-md-4 in this case? Thanks

Comment: are you talking about the above structure only?

Comment: Yes, using <tr> and <td>

Comment: can you edit the above code to the td tr you are talking about.

Comment: do you want to set the width of one td to col-lg-4?? if it is. it will depend on the parent element.

Comment: Yes, I'd like fixed width